# Spring MVC : Unable to extract pathvariable value in a controller

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

I am working on Spring-MVC. I am using a JSP page, which is called with variables automatically generated beforehand and I must copy them inside the controller for further processing. However the value of it is {variablename}. I will post the code and what I am trying to do. Kindly have a look.

Console output :

```
Token value is{token}
Token verification failed
Token in controller is{token}
User and password is :myemail@gmail.com and password checkpassword
```

Controller code :

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/resetpassword")
    public String newPasswordPage(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("person", new Person());
        return "resetpassword";
    }
   @RequestMapping(value = "/newpassword/{token}")
   public String changePasswordFunction(@ModelAttribute("person") Person person, Model model, @PathVariable("token") String token){
        if(person.getNewpassword() == null){

            return "resetpassword";
        } else {
            personService.changePassword(token,person.getUsername(),person.getPassword());
            System.out.println("Token in controller is"+token);
            System.out.println("User and password is :"+person.getUsername()+" and password "+person.getNewpassword());
            model.addAttribute("person",person);
            return "redirect:/";
        }
    }
```

Resetpassword.jsp :

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<c:url var="addAction" value="/newpassword/{token}" ></c:url>
<form:form action="${addAction}" commandName="person">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <form:label path="username">
                    <spring:message text="username"/>
                </form:label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form:input path="username"  />
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <form:label path="token">
                    <spring:message text="token"/>
                </form:label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form:input path="token"  />
            </td>
        </tr>


        <tr>
            <td>
                <form:label path="newpassword">
                    <spring:message text="newpassword"/>
                </form:label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form:input path="newpassword"  />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is nothing to extract... The value of `token` is `{token}` as you hardcoded that into your page. You are submitting a parameter with the name token and that isn't part of the URI.

Comment: My uri looks like this localhost:8085/newpassword/emailid:tokens. The URL is automatically generated and sent to user. How can I extract the emailid:tokens as one entity? Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are just missing the $ for your token in c:url. Please try

```
<c:url var="addAction" value="/newpassword/${token}" ></c:url>
```

Comment: Should I do same in controller as well?

Comment: Nope. Controller is fine.

Comment: I think something is wrong, as now when I click the submit button, the method in controller is not getting called... No matter how many times I press it.

Comment: Please post the URL you see after pressing the button

Comment: The url remains same i.e http://localhost:8085/newpassword/myemail@gmail.com:1416653626993:VZelDNRi9pU_ZD6bCzuyFMaJU-Y2pXU7wajMD4I8gtg

Comment: Silly mistake, i was check person.getPassword instead of person.getNewPassword(). Its resolved, thank you very much. I am marking your answer.

Answer (score 1):

One way I found very useful to debug this sort of controller issues is to write a unit test using [spring MVC Test Framework](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/integration-testing.html#spring-mvc-test-framework) :

```
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.ResultActions;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;

public class YourControllerTest {

    private YourController yourController;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        yourController = new YourController();
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(yourController).build();

    }

    @Test
    public void testChangePasswordFunction() throws Exception {

        ResultActions resultActions = mockMvc
                .perform(get("/newpassword/myemail@gmail.com:1416653626993:VZelDNRi9pU_ZD6bCzuyFMaJU-Y2pXU7wajMD4I8gtg"));

        resultActions.andExpect(status().isFound());


    }
}
```

Running the test above would output the following to the console (you may want to comment out the call personService.changePassword() to simplify unit test setup, or use a mocking framework to mock the person service object):

```
Token in controller ismyemail@gmail.com:1416653626993:VZelDNRi9pU_ZD6bCzuyFMaJU-Y2pXU7wajMD4I8gtg
```

Now if you wanted to extract variables which seem to be separated by a ":" character, you can change the request mapping method signature to something like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/newpassword/{token1}:{token2}:{token3}")
public String changePasswordFunction(@ModelAttribute("person") Person person, Model model, @PathVariable("token1") String token1, @PathVariable("token2") String token2, @PathVariable("token3") String token3)
```